# MVC Global.asax Variable and Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Quick Question...

In MVC5, are variables in the Global.asax accessible via all sessions or does MVC create and instance of Global for each session?

Example

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication 
{

    public static string Current_UserName = "";

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Current_UserName = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

So would user A `Current_UserName` change when user B loads the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Current_UserName` would essentially be the last user that initialized their session.  So user B who accesses the app after user A would show "B" in the static variable.

Answer (score 0):

As `Current_UserName` user is static, the last assigned user will remain in that variable. I mean, the last session initiated user.